# Java Object Construction and Enclosing Method

Tags: java, constructor, jvm, initialization

I've been looking for a book or some document to better explain what's going on here:

```
System.out.println(">constructor>" + new Object().getClass().getEnclosingConstructor());
```

Output:: >constructor >null

However,

```
System.out.println(">constructor>" + new Object(){/**/}.getClass().getEnclosingConstructor().toString());
```

Output:: >constructor >packageInformation.ClassConstructor()

I know this has something to do ... probably ... with a static initialization sequence.

My question is:  **How does that work and where can I read more about this?**

Thanks.

Comment: @TheLostMind: You need to place those lines inside a constructor to make `getEnclosingConstructor` return anything `!= null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read about that in the [javadoc for `Class.getEnclosingConstructor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnclosingConstructor--):

> If this `Class` object represents a local or anonymous class within a constructor, returns a `Constructor` object representing the immediately enclosing constructor of the underlying class. Returns `null` otherwise.

Since `Object` isn't a anonymus class, `null` is returned in the first case.

`new Object(){/**/}` creates a instance of a anonymus class extending `Object`, which is why a non-`null` value is returned, if `new Object(){/**/}.getClass().getEnclosingConstructor()` is placed inside a constructor.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a " this is what the vm does; i.e. looks up this and that " ... on a low level approach.